# Audio Input and Output problems

Tags: windows-7, audio, speakers

There's a problem with my audio that I searched all over Google but never found an answer.
So what happens is that when I plug earphones in, the sound would come out from the speaker instead. In order to make it go through the earphones, I had to keep them plugged in and restart my computer, and once I unplug them, the sound will never go through the earphones again unless I restart again.
I check my earphones, they work perfectly fine on my phone so it has to be my computer's problem.
When I go into the "Change sound card setting" from Start, under the Playback tab, the only thing that is there is the Speakers, no Headphones.

Also, when I try to record something with my computer, it always chops off the first sound of every sentence. For example, saying "Hello" would ended up sound like "Ello", and the volume is so much lower, I can barely hear what I recorded.

Any suggestion on how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like an an operating system issue in managing audio devices, please try the following steps and see if that helps,

> Please select the ear phones as default device using "Set Default" option  as shown the picture.
>
> Try with different jack and different earphone to isolate the issue with the hardware or OS[image]

Comment: the only thing that shows up in this window is the first speaker that you have there. Speakers Realtek High Definition Audio thing